# How to set the folder and file access permission inheritance as parent folder automatically in Ubuntu Server ?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-server

How to set the folder and file access permission inheritance as parent folder automatically in Ubuntu Server ?

I want the parent folder permission to be applied on the child files and folders and sub folders as when they are created. 
An now i am facing the problem of changing the permission to folder every time once they are created.

please guide me

Answer (score 0):

try chmod -R and rights

e.g.: 
chmod -R ugo+rwx directory